# Is 0 an element of this set?

Tags: real-analysis

I am working on a question that depends on this (possibly very basic) idea and I need help. My intuition tells me that $0$ is not an element of this set, because $0$ does not equal $\frac1n$ for any natural number $n$, but I don't know if that is rigorous enough, or even correct at all.

Let $A = \{\frac1n\}$ for all $n$ in the set of natural numbers.

Is $0$ an element of $A$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it is not indeed

$$\frac 1n=0$$

has not solution.

What is true is that $0$ is the [infimum](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum) of the set since as $n\to \infty$

$$\frac 1n\to 0$$

Answer (score 3):

No.

If $0 = \frac1n$, multiply both sides by $n$, we get $0=1$ which is a contradiction.

It is a limit point of the set though.

Comment: Thanks so much to both of you - your help is much appreciated. I am unable to upvote, but please accept this instead: ^ ^

Answer (score 3):

No. You may confuse with the limit of the sequence $1/n$. Is is true that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$, but $0\notin A$.

Proof: Suppose otherwise that $0\in A$. Hence, there exist a positive integer $n$ such that $\frac{1}{n}=0$. But this equation is of-course is unsolvable. QED

Answer (score 1):

No.

If $0$ is in set A then there would be a $n$ such that $$\frac{1}{n} = 0$$
which is not possible.